# SpringBoot Swagger UI - Get swagger.json of specific Controller

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui

I have a SpringBoot Application which implements many Rest Controllers exposing multiple endpoints.

Each Rest Controller expects requests from a different Application/System, let's say:

RestControllerA - Called by System A
RestControllerB - Called by System B
...

Swagger provides the /api-docs endpoint, which provides the swagger.json for all RestControllers.

Is there a way to generate and provide the swagger.json to each system, only for the RestController it is interested into? For example I want to generate the swagger.json only for RestControllerA.
Adding to this, is there a way to generate the swagger.json for a specific endpoint of a controller?

(I'm using the springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0 dependency)